# ServiceStack OrmLite + Foreign Key

Tags: foreign-keys, ormlite-servicestack

I've got the asp.net forms authentication tables in place, and I'd like to create a FK to one of the tables.

Is this possible without creating a type to be used with the attribute?

Answer (score 0):

In the end, I created another skelton poco class that matched the table, this enabled me to place the foreign key.